# sentence meaning "to be wrapped up in oneself"

Tags: jokes

Halloween Joke:

> Why do mummies have trouble keeping friends? They're so wrapped up in themselves ...

What is "wrapped up in themselves"?

Comment: One question at a time please. I've edited.

Comment: If you're *wrapped up in yourself*, you're ***self-obsessed*** (or perhaps ***self-absorbed***) - meaning you're only interested in yourself. Usually with the implication *not interested other people's concerns* (i.e. - *selfish*), but sometimes more neutrally *introspective, not interested in external situations or events*.

Comment: The joke is funny because it's a **pun** or a **play on words**.  This kind of humor -- mixing up a word or phrase that has two (or more) different meanings -- is common in English.  Similar riddle:   Q:  When is a door not a door?  A: When it is [ajar](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/ajar).

Answer (score 3):

To be **wrapped up in yourself** means to be egotistical, narcissistic.  The mummy is wrapped up in a different way, in cloth strips.

Answer (score 2):

"Wrapped up" means that person's attention is consumed by something. 
She is so wrapped up in that tv show. She is only paying attention to that tv show.
To be wrapped up in yourself means you are only focused on yourself and your concerns. Selfish, self-centered.

This is a joke because mummies are wrapped in paper/cloth.